# Upper hemisphere of $S^2$ homeomorphic to the ball $B^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

How can I show that the upper hemisphere E is homeomorphic to the ball $B^2$ I can see it intuitively, but I don't know how to prove it rigorously. I need it to prove the following theorem

There is no continous antipode-preserving map $g : S^2 \rightarrow S^1$

Comment: How about projection to $(x,y,0)$?

Comment: can you please elaborate more ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map $(x,y,z)\mapsto (x,y,0)$ is a continuous bijection from $E$ to $B^2$ with continuous inverse $(x,y,0)\mapsto (x,y,\sqrt{1-(x^2+y^2)})$

Comment: can you give me the explicit definition of $B^2$ is it $\{(x_1,...,x_n) | x_1^2 + .... + x_n^2 \leq 1\}$ ?

Comment: $B^2=\{(x_1,x_2)|x_1^2+x_2^2\leq1\}\cong \{(x_1,x_2,0)|x_1^2+x_2^2\leq1\}$